# Adobe Photoshop Extension Open save As dialog

Tags: javascript, adobe

I am a developer working on writing a script for Adobe Photoshop to be able to open photoshop native window of "Save As.." using below code:

```
var jpgFile = new File(" ");
var jpgSaveOptions = new JPEGSaveOptions();
var doc = app.activeDocument.saveAs(jpgFile, jpgSaveOptions, true, Extension.LOWERCASE);
```

This code works on Windows 10 and MacOS on all versions of Photoshop  except *Photoshop version 19.1.8 on MacOS*, where I get below error:

> Fatal Error: General Photoshop error occurred. This functionality may
>   not be available in this version of Photoshop.

I tried few things, like replacing space in new File object with blank string, a hard-coded path for a file but nothing seems to work.
Any help is highly appreciated.

Comment: I had no problem executing this command on 19.1.8 on Mac (I only changed `new File(" ");` to `new File(Folder.desktop + "/file.jpg");` because I don't think an empty path makes sense)

Comment: Thanks for the response, Sergey. I see the same response too on Mac. But what I want to achieve here is to be able to open the native Save As dialog of Photoshop and give user the option to save the file to a location of his choice. Also, and more importantly, I want to give user the options window that follows the Save As window where the user can make changes in options like Matt, Quality and other Format Options. Any input will be highly appreciated.

Comment: Ah, got it now. I'll write my answer shortly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure why saving an empty `File` shows a `Save As` dialog in other versions, I'd expect the same error message :/ Anyway, there're two things you can do.

- Set a Photoshop option to always display dialogs before saving a document and then set the default value:

  ```
  var curDialogModes = app.displayDialogs; //current displayDialogs options
  app.displayDialogs = DialogModes.ALL; //explicitely show all dialogs

  var jpgFile = new File(Folder.desktop + "/file.jpg");
  var jpgSaveOptions = new JPEGSaveOptions();
  try
  {
      var doc = app.activeDocument.saveAs(jpgFile, jpgSaveOptions, true, Extension.LOWERCASE);
  }
  catch (e)
  {
      if (e.number != 8007)
      //8007 is a code for "operation cancelled"
      //so we only show a message if something else has happened
      {
          alert(e);
      }
  }

  app.displayDialogs = curDialogModes // restoring displayDialogs back to original value
  ```
- use Action Manager code (you can get it from ScriptListener plugin) and change `DialogModes.NO` to `DialogModes.ALL` just for that function — in this case you don't change it globally but only for this action.

  ```
  function saveJPG(path)
  {
      var desc9 = new ActionDescriptor();
      var desc10 = new ActionDescriptor();
      desc10.putInteger(charIDToTypeID('EQlt'), 10);
      desc10.putEnumerated(charIDToTypeID('MttC'), charIDToTypeID('MttC'), charIDToTypeID('None'));
      desc9.putObject(charIDToTypeID('As  '), charIDToTypeID('JPEG'), desc10);
      desc9.putPath(charIDToTypeID('In  '), new File(path));
      desc9.putInteger(charIDToTypeID('DocI'), 400);
      desc9.putBoolean(charIDToTypeID('Cpy '), true);
      desc9.putEnumerated(stringIDToTypeID('saveStage'), stringIDToTypeID('saveStageType'), stringIDToTypeID('saveBegin'));
      try
      {
          executeAction(charIDToTypeID('save'), desc9, DialogModes.ALL); // here the default DialogModes is DialogModes.NO
      }
      catch (e)
      {
          if (e.number != 8007)
          //8007 is a code for "operation cancelled"
          //so we only show a message if something else has happened
          {
              alert(e);
          }
      }
  }

  saveJPG(Folder.desktop + "/file.jpg")
  ```

Note that when you're showing dialogs, cancelling it will throw an error with a code 8007, so use try/catch to deal with it.

Comment: If so, please mark question as accepted so it'll be visible as working for everyone. Cheers